# Inverse Map where getValue returns a List

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, inverse

I would like to transform a `Map<String, List<Object>>` so it becomes `Map<String, String>`. If it were just `Map<String, Object>` it is easy in Java8;

```
stream().collect(k -> k.getValue().getMyKey(), Entry::getKey);
```

But this will not work because getValue returns a List `Map<List<Object>, String>` in my example. Assume Object contains a getter to be used for the key and that `Object` does not contain the key in the first map.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you explain the bit...  *and that Object does not contain the key in the first map.* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream over the list of objects and extract the key you need then `map` --> `flatten` --> `toMap`

```
source.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                     .stream()
                     .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getMyKey(), e.getKey())))
      .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

use a merge function if there is expected to be duplicate `getMyKey()` values:

```
source.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                     .stream()
                     .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getMyKey(), e.getKey())))
      .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue, (l, r) -> l));
```

**Note:** the above uses the source map keys as the values of the resulting map as that's what you seem to be illustrating in your post, if however you want the key of the source map to remain as the key of the resulting map then change `new SimpleEntry<>(x.getMyKey(), e.getKey())` to `new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),x.getMyKey())`.

Answer (score 1):

If preference could be to choose *any* amongst the multiple values mapped as a *key*, you can simply use:

```
Map<String, List<YourObject>> existing = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
existing.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(v1 -> output.put(v1.getMyKey(), k)));
```

Essentially this would put the 'first' such `myKey` along with its corresponding value which was the `key` of the existing map.